# FPV camera inertia/movement

Tags: animation, camera

I'm trying to make a sci-fi short movie. I have a camera inside the cockpit of an helicopter, and I would like to have some inertia or a small movement when the helicopter moves. Right now I have a camera parented to the helicopter, but it stays fixed as you see here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-lN1HLvJDk

I like to have some movement when the helicopter turns or banks, like in this Star Citizen trailer:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rQDDc7Pxlc

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is animate the camera too. You're already animating the helicopter to displace the camera. Now animate the camera to give it the desired details, as if the person inside was moving its head.

There might be a script or something to do it automatically, but seems to me like it would be actually more complicated.

Comment: I was thinking of something possible via parenting/traking or maybe with the use of bones.